# Apple script to set the font of a outlook appointment,

Tags: ios, applescript

I am using the below apple script to set outlook appointment in outlook calendar. It is working fine. Now I need to set the font to courier new for the content. How Can I set the font through apple script.

```
string MainScript = @"tell application ""Microsoft Outlook""

                set theSubject to ""vSubject""
                set theContent to ""vContent""
                set StartSate to current date
                set day of StartSate to vStartDay -- important
                set month of StartSate to vStartMonth
                set year of StartSate to vStartYear
                set hours of StartSate to vStartHour
                set minutes of StartSate to vStartMinutes
                set seconds of StartSate to vStartSeconds


                set EndDate to current date
                set day of EndDate to vEndDay -- important
                set month of EndDate to vEndMonth
                set year of EndDate to vEndYear
                set hours of EndDate to vEndHour
                set minutes of EndDate to vEndMinutes
                set seconds of EndDate to vEndSeconds


                set newAppointment to make new calendar event with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, start time:StartSate, end time:EndDate}



            end tell";
```